# Automount at boot in /etc/fstab taking very long time after 15.04 upgrade

Tags: boot, samba, 15.04, cifs

After my recent upgrade to 15.04, I noticed that the boot is taking a very long time -- I have an SSD, and previously boot to the login screen was taking about 7-8 seconds. Now it's more like 35-45.

I switched to the terminal output during the wait, and noticed that is sitting on a line mentioning my automount for a long time before moving on -- this did not appear in 14.10.

I removed the lines from my /etc/fstab, and the boot time to login screen returned to about 7-8 seconds. I would like to have these mounted at boot time, though -- any ideas? The relevant lines from my fstab are:

```
//192.168.1.110/Public /mnt/titanpublic cifs iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
//192.168.1.110/backups /mnt/titanbackups cifs iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

The relevant lines from journalctl are:

```
May 06 11:28:11 Skyhawk-5 systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/titanbackups...
May 06 11:28:11 Skyhawk-5 systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth.
May 06 11:28:11 Skyhawk-5 systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth.
May 06 11:28:12 Skyhawk-5 ntpdate[1193]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.327939 sec
May 06 11:28:13 Skyhawk-5 NetworkManager[848]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set disabled
May 06 11:28:13 Skyhawk-5 NetworkManager[848]: <info> WWAN hardware radio set enabled
May 06 11:29:42 Skyhawk-5 mount[1210]: Timed out
May 06 11:29:42 Skyhawk-5 systemd[1]: mnt-titanpublic.mount mounting timed out. Stopping.
May 06 11:29:42 Skyhawk-5 systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/titanpublic.
May 06 11:29:42 Skyhawk-5 systemd[1]: mnt-titanbackups.mount mounting timed out. Stopping.
May 06 11:29:42 Skyhawk-5 systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/titanbackups.
```

Later there is

```
May 06 11:29:42 Skyhawk-5 systemd[1]: Unit mnt-titanpublic.mount entered failed state.
May 06 11:29:42 Skyhawk-5 systemd[1]: Unit mnt-titanbackups.mount entered failed state.
```

---

Looks like it's related to systemd/upstart -- when I started from the GRUB menu with a kernel with the upstart option, the delay went away.

EDIT: Though it starts up normally with these existing fstab lines even with systemd, granted you added the "guest" parameter to your mount strings in /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.1.110/Public /mnt/titanpublic cifs guest,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
//192.168.1.110/backups /mnt/titanbackups cifs guest,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

So, solution: add "guest" to these strings in /etc/fstab with Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into the problem where network services try to start before the network is actually up and running.
After running `sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service` the services will wait till the network is online.

Comment: Thank you your response.  I ran the command you mentioned, and then re-added the lines back to my /etc/fstab file.

Unfortunately, the pause still happened, but I managed to write it down quickly while switching to the console output during boot:

    Mounting /mnt/titanbackupups...ine.ne.tcher service....ystem changes...p.link was shutdown...

Comment: You can use `journalctl` to view the boot log once the boot is done. Search for the error there and edit it in you question.

Comment: I dont see anything below. Anyway please dont post this as comments/edit the comments. Edit it in your question.

Comment: Ah, no prob -- I thought you meant in the comment below.  Added the relevant lines to the question above.

Comment: Try adding `timeo=14` to the options in `/etc/fstab`: `//192.168.1.110/Public /mnt/titanpublic cifs iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,timeo=14 0 0`

Comment: Added timeo=14, but no change (it might've taken longer).

I can run "sudo mount //192.168.1.110/Public /mnt/titanpublic" after boot up (if I remove these lines), and it runs quickly, and mounts the drive (though it asks me for a root password).

Comment: Yes the problom is waiting time at boot because something the mount depends on is not ready. You can try the following flags, they work fine for my NAS: `noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev`